# Insertar varios campos vacíos

Tags: php

En un formulario que debe llenar el usuario tengo varios campos opcionales que pueden ser llenados o no por el usuario para ser insertados en una base de datos, el problema es que no consigo que eso suceda, tengo 4 campos opcionales marca, modelo, edicion y telefono2

El usuario podría o no llenar cualquiera de esos campos, pero no consigo que se cumpla la primera condición con el primer insert, solo pasa al segundo insert así llene cualquiera de los que pueden ser nulos.
Aquí mi archivo para insertar

```
<?php
session_start();
include "./conexion.php";
if(!isset($_SESSION['datos_logueo'])){header("location: ./index.php");}
$arreglousuario = $_SESSION['datos_logueo'];
$id = $arreglousuario['id_usuario'];

if(isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['descripcion']) 
&& isset($_POST['precio']) && isset($_POST['inventario']) && isset($_POST['ubicacion']) 
&& isset($_POST['telefono1'])){
   
 
  $fecha = new DateTime();
  if(!empty($_POST['marca']) || !empty($_POST['modelo']) || !empty($_POST['edicion']) || !empty($_POST['telefono2'])){
    $sql1 = $conexion->query("insert into publicacion
    (nombre,marca,modelo,edicion,descripcion,precio,inventario,ubicacion,telefono1,
    telefono2,fecha_publicacion,estatus_publicacion,id_usuario,id_estado,
    id_categoria,id_subcategoria) values
                        ( 
                        '".$_POST['nombre']."',
                        '".$_POST['marca']."',
                        '".$_POST['modelo']."',
                        '".$_POST['edicion']."',
                        '".$_POST['descripcion']."',
                        ".$_POST['precio'].",
                        ".$_POST['inventario'].",
                        '".$_POST['ubicacion']."',
                        ".$_POST['telefono1'].",
                        ".$_POST['telefono2'].",
                        '{$fecha->format('YmdHis')}',
                        '1',
                        $id,
                        '".$_POST['estado']."',
                        '".$_POST['categoria']."',
                        '".$_POST['subcategoria']."'
                      )
                        ")or die ($conexion->error);
                       header("Location: ../admin/publicacion.php?success"); 
        }else{
         
          $fecha = new DateTime();
          $sql2 = $conexion->query("insert into publicacion
          (nombre,descripcion,precio,inventario,ubicacion,telefono1,
          fecha_publicacion,estatus_publicacion,id_usuario,id_estado,
          id_categoria,id_subcategoria) values
                              ( 
                              '".$_POST['nombre']."',
                              '".$_POST['descripcion']."',
                              ".$_POST['precio'].",
                              ".$_POST['inventario'].",
                              '".$_POST['ubicacion']."',
                              ".$_POST['telefono1'].",
                              '{$fecha->format('YmdHis')}',
                              '1',
                              $id,
                              '".$_POST['estado']."',
                              '".$_POST['categoria']."',
                              '".$_POST['subcategoria']."'
                            )
                              ")or die ($conexion->error);
                             header("Location: ../admin/publicacion.php?success"); 
                      
    }
}

?>
```

**Código formulario**

```html
<!-- Modal Insertar Publicacion -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="../php/insertarpublicacion.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Crear Publicación</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="marca">Marca (Opcional)</label>
                        <input type="text" name="marca" placeholder="marca del producto" id="marca" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="modelo">Modelo (Opcional)</label>
                        <input type="text" name="modelo" placeholder="modelo del producto" id="modelo" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="edicion">Edición (Opcional)</label>
                        <input type="text" name="edicion" placeholder="edición o año del producto" id="edicion" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="descripcion">Descripción</label>
                        <input type="text" name="descripcion" placeholder="descripcion publicacion" id="descripcion" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="precio">Precio</label>
                        <input type="number" min="0" name="precio" placeholder="precio" id="precio" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inventario"> Inventario</label>
                        <input type="number" min="0" name="inventario" placeholder="Cantidad en inventario que posee del producto" id="inventario" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ubicacion">Ubicación del vendedor</label>
                        <input type="text" name="ubicacion" placeholder="ciudad donde se ubica el vendedor" id="ubicacion" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="telefono1">Teléfono</label>
                        <input type="text" name="telefono1" placeholder="número de contacto" id="telefono1" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="telefono2">Teléfono Opcional</label>
                        <input type="text" name="telefono2" placeholder="número de contacto" id="telefono2" class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                    <fieldset class="step">
                        <legend>Agregar Imágenes máximo 6</legend>
                        <div id="content2"> <a href="javascript:;" id="upload">Subir Foto</a>
                            <ul id="gallery">
                                <!-- Cargar Fotos -->
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="categoria">Categoria</label>
                        <select name="categoria" id="categoria" class="form-control">
                            <?php
                                $cat = $conexion->query("select * from categorias") or die ($conexion->error);
                                while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($cat)) {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $fila['id_categoria'] . '">' . $fila['nombre'] . '</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="subcategoria">Subcategoria</label>
                        <select name="subcategoria" id="subcategoria" class="form-control" >
                            <?php
                                $cat = $conexion->query("select * from subcategorias") or die ($conexion->error);
                                while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($cat)) {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $fila['id_subcategoria'] . '">' . $fila['nombre'] . '</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="estado">Estado</label>
                        <select name="estado" id="estado" class="form-control">
                            <?php
                                $estados = $conexion->query("select * from estados") or die ($conexion->error);
                                while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($estados)) {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $fila['id_estado'] . '">' . $fila['nombre'] . '</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="guardar" input="input" value="guardar">Guardar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Gracias de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: con qué etiqueta manejas esos datos? una opción también es tener valores por default en esos campos en la base de datos.

Comment: Hola Mau gracias por responder, esos campos en la bd son nulos por defecto

Comment: Hola, por favor pega un screenshot de los campos de tu tabla en la base de datos

Comment: Hola Fernando, ya lo he agragado

Comment: Podrías mostrar el código del formulario?

Comment: Hola @azeós gracias por responder, ya lo coloque.

Comment: te preguntaba como manejas esos datos en tu aplicación, yo hice eso con campos checkbox y colocaba algo del lado de php similar a esto if(isset($_post['campo'])){ campodb=1}else{campodb=0}

Comment: Probá lo siguiente: completá todos los campos y antes del primer `if` hacé un `print_r($_POST); exit;` y decinos que devuelve. Tal vez no están llegando algunos campos.

Comment: @MauEspaña ¿pero eran campos numéricos?

Comment: @azeós el primer if que es donde viajan los datos que son obligatorios funciona, de hecho ese if no hace ninguna función por el momento porque igual la función required no permite que el campo no se llene, sin embargo igual allí me faltan validaciones con java script

Comment: Perdón pero entonces no entiendo tu pregunta.

Comment: No esos no son campos numericos, son campos booleanos, (true, false) @Apalazon

Comment: @azeós, en el formulario hay datos obligatorios y datos opcionales, el primer if que sería if(isset($_POST['nombre']) etc...etc..etc. me verifica que los datos obligatorios sean llenados por el usuario, es una condición sumada al código antes del insert aunque de igual manera ya en el HTML el input tiene la función required. Pero en ese formulario existen 4 valores más que son opcionales, el usuario de esos 4 podría llenar 2 ó 1 ó 3 ó los 4 ó ninguno.